# Remote Outlet Switching Options

Tags: home-automation

I have a switch that controls an outlet on the other side of the room. On the other wall there are two outlets that I have lamps plugged into. It would be really great if i could use that switch to turn those lamps on and off with out having to run a extension cord across the room.

I have a seen smart switches, smart wall outlets, smart electric cords, to smart light bulb intermediary sockets.

What is important to me is that I have price options when buying and installing the solution, and of course it all works together when installed.

P.S. an Developer API would be nice as well.

So what are my options?

Comment: Fortunately or unfortunately, you have many, many options available to you these days -- you didn't even mention the bulbs and switches with direct WiFi communications -- and at this point the topic is probably too broad to cover in a Stack Exchange question, especially since product recommendations are generally considered out of scope.

Comment: Well i defiantly see the similarity but the solutions provided fall far short of what i'm looking for as a solution. Is there a way I should rephrase the question or refine it's scope?